# How do I pass data from a variable in a view to a view model class

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift3, swiftui-environment, swift5.7

I have data contained in a variable called `selectedFolderId`, and the intent of this is I want to pass this data in this variable into a class whereby I read contents of my database from firestore anytime the `ShoppingListItemsView` loads.

I would appreciate help from anyone if they can explain and show me how to pass this data from my `ShoppingListItemsView` into my `ListRepository` class where i will further use this data to do a query.

Here are the `ShoppingListItemsView` and the `ListRepository` classes:

```
import SwiftUI
import November

struct ShoppingListItemsView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var taskListVM = ShoppingListItemsViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionService: SessionServiceImpl
    @EnvironmentObject var searchBarModel: SearchBarModel
    @ObservedObject var folderListVM = FolderListViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var listRepository = ListRepository()
    
    let tasks = testDataTasks
    
    var selectedFolderTitle = ""
    var selectedFolderDate = ""
    var selectedFolderId = ""
    
    @State var presentANewItem = false
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                List{
                    ForEach(taskListVM.taskCellViewModels){ taskCellVM in
                        TaskCell(taskCellVM: taskCellVM)
                    }
                    if(presentANewItem == true){
                        TaskCell(taskCellVM: ShoppingListItemCellViewModel(task: ListItem(listTitle: "", completed: false, selectedFolderId: selectedFolderId))) { task in
                            self.taskListVM.addTask(task: task)
                            self.presentANewItem.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
//                .onAppear {
//                    // Set the default to clear
//                    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
//                }
                Button (action: { self.presentANewItem.toggle() }, label : {
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text("Add New Item")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 15.0))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                    .padding(3)
                    .background(Color.cartvoltDarkBlue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .shadow(color: Color.cartvoltDarkBlue.opacity(0.9), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
                })
                .padding(.bottom)

            }
            .onAppear{
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("\(selectedFolderTitle) • \(selectedFolderDate)")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class ListRepository: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var tasks = [ListItem]()
    @Published var selectedFolderId = ""
    
    init(){
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
        db.collection("listItems")
            .order(by: "createdTime")
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId)
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                self.tasks = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                    do {
                        let x = try document.data(as: ListItem.self)
                        return x
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Preferably I would like to move the data contained in the `selectedFolderId` variable in `ShoppingListItemsView` when it loads, as you can see the `onAppear{}`, into the `selectedFolderId` variable in `ListRepository` class where I will later use it in a query.

Would mean a lot if someone can work this out for me

Answer (score 0):

Hi Emere and welcome to SO. To get fast and quality answers please read this article [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Any way your case doesn't seems difficile and you can achieve your goal by creating a `func` in `ListRepository` that will accept an argument from `ShoppingListItemsView` and rewrite `selectedFolderId`. Call that func from your view anytime when you want to set new `selectedFolderId`.

Add this func to `ListRepository`:

```
func setSelectedFolderId(id: String) {
    self.selectedFolderId = id
}
```

Add this modification to View that should change `selectedFolderIs` when you tap on item and pass new value into the function.

```
.onTapGesture { listRepository.setSelectedFolderId(id: String) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to **ListRepository**

```
func selectedFolderId(id: String) {
    self.selectedFolderId = id
}
```

and replace in **ShoppingListItemsView**

```
ForEach(taskListVM.taskCellViewModels){ taskCellVM in
  TaskCell(taskCellVM: taskCellVM)
}
```

by

```
ForEach(taskListVM.taskCellViewModels){ taskCellVM in
  TaskCell(taskCellVM: taskCellVM)
    .onTapGesture { listRepository.selectedFolderId(id: taskCellVM.id) }
}
```

*I assumed it is taskCellVM.id which gives the id*

With each tap on the cell, the id will change